# C++ change a member of derived class to it's specialized version

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's say I have two classes - **Graph** and **Vertex** that have some basic members and methods that are needed to represent a general Graph. They are already fully implemented and works perfectly for standard graphs.

```
class Vertex { 
    int id;
    Vertex(int id) : id(id) {}
    // ...
}

class Graph {
    std::vector<Vertex *> vertices;
    void addVertex(int id) {
        vertices.push_back(new Vertex(id));
    }
    // ...
}
```

And I'd like to extend those classes to add some problem-related functionality. For example, I want to have a **Vertex** that stores its colour. That's why I declare another class, called **VertexC**, which inherits from **Vertex** and adds a new member. So now I would like to have a specialized version of **Graph** - **GraphC** that can manage new **VertexC** properties.

```
class VertexC: Vertex {
    string colour;
    string getColour() {
        return colour;
    }
}

class GraphC: Graph {
    void doSomething(string colour) {
        for(auto &v: vertices) {
            if(v->getColour() == "red") // Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't do this because **Graph::vertices** are of type **Vertex *** and not **VertexC *** so they don't have **getColour()** method. Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Edit: Changed the description a bit to introduce my problem in a more direct way.

Comment: The thing that uses them either needs colors or it doesn't.   if it needs colors, it should always take a vertexc.  if not, then it shouldn't.   You're on the cusp of doing something that screams poor design by doing a dynamic_cast on the list of vertex objects to check if they're vertexc objects at runtime.  Don't do this.  The answer, instead is to take out vertices from Graph, make it an interface-only class, then make a color graph and a no-color graph that each store the appropriate vertex type for what they need.  You could also use a template to specify what type of Vertex to store

Comment: @xaxxon everything sounds reasonable but the thing is that the Graph class is already implemented and it provides an enormous number of methods that you may need to use graphs. Don't you think that providing functions not really related to a graph itself but rather to some problem-related specifics should be done in some specialized class that inherits main implementation from Graph class?

Comment: I recommend searching for virtual methods

Comment: "Graph class is already implemented" - it sounds like you're mis-using it as a base class then.   There's a fundamental design schism between what it sounds like Graph was designed for and what you're trying to use it for.  Not every class makes a good base class.

Comment: Your additional requirements should be spelled out in your question to motivate the kind of answer you are looking for. However, since `Graph` cannot store `VertexC` (because of the way `addVertex` is defined), the design of `GraphC` seems flawed.

Comment: Maybe I am. What I would like to do is to extend functionality of Graph class to fit my problem assumptions. Perhaps adding needed methods to original Graph class would be an easiest solution.

Comment: If you are open to modifying `Graph`, it is better to refactor it into a template so that it can store different kinds of `Vertex`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to templatize the Graph class. Something like:

```
template<typename TVert> class Graph
{
    std::vector<TVert> vertices;
    // ...
};
```

which means the specialization can then be declared as:

```
class GraphC : public Graph<VertexC*>
{
    // ...
};
```

Something may need to be done about the addVertex method though. It could be declared as follows:

```
void addVertex(int id)
{
    vertices.push_back(new TVert(id));
}
```

Though this would mean any specializations of the Graph class must only be of types that include a constructor that takes a single int argument. An alternative would be something like:

```
void addVertex(TVert vert)
{
    vertices.push_back(vert);
}
```

Note also the addition of the public keyword in the class declaration of GraphC. This would be required to make Graph's addVertex method available through instances of GraphC.